# FileNotFoundException when submitting to Kubernetes Spark cluster

Tags: python, docker, apache-spark, kubernetes, pyspark

I am using Spark 2.4 and trying to submit a job on a kubernetes cluster. I used this tutorial to set up the service accounts and authentication for my cluster:
https://www.oak-tree.tech/blog/spark-kubernetes-primer

The code below is my `spark-submit` code which I am running inside my docker container:

```
/opt/spark/bin/spark-submit --name sparkpi-test1 \
--master k8s://<k8s-apiserver-host-for-my-cluster>:<my-port> \
--deploy-mode cluster  \
--class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi  \
--conf spark.kubernetes.driver.pod.name=$SPARK_DRIVER_NAME  \
--conf spark.kubernetes.authenticate.subdmission.caCertFile=$K8S_CACERT  \
--conf spark.kubernetes.authenticate.submission.oauthTokenFile=$K8S_TOKEN  \
--conf spark.kubernetes.authenticate.driver.serviceAccountName=$SA  \
--conf spark.kubernetes.namespace=$SPARK_NAMESPACE  \
--conf spark.executor.instances=2  \
--conf spark.kubernetes.container.image=$DOCKER-IMAGE  \
--conf spark.kubernetes.container.image.pullPolicy=Always \
local:///opt/spark/work-dir/program_code/data/code.py
```

However, this generates the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException:  (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at org.spark_project.guava.io.Files$FileByteSource.openStream(Files.java:124)
    at org.spark_project.guava.io.Files$FileByteSource.openStream(Files.java:114)
    at org.spark_project.guava.io.ByteSource$AsCharSource.openStream(ByteSource.java:287)
    at org.spark_project.guava.io.CharSource.read(CharSource.java:136)
    at org.spark_project.guava.io.Files.toString(Files.java:369)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.k8s.SparkKubernetesClientFactory$$anonfun$5.apply(SparkKubernetesClientFactory.scala:74)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.k8s.SparkKubernetesClientFactory$$anonfun$5.apply(SparkKubernetesClientFactory.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.k8s.SparkKubernetesClientFactory$OptionConfigurableConfigBuilder$$anonfun$withOption$extension$1.apply(SparkKubernetesClientFactory.scala:98)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.k8s.SparkKubernetesClientFactory$OptionConfigurableConfigBuilder$$anonfun$withOption$extension$1.apply(SparkKubernetesClientFactory.scala:97)
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.k8s.SparkKubernetesClientFactory$OptionConfigurableConfigBuilder$.withOption$extension(SparkKubernetesClientFactory.scala:97)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.k8s.SparkKubernetesClientFactory$.createKubernetesClient(SparkKubernetesClientFactory.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.k8s.submit.KubernetesClientApplication$$anonfun$run$4.apply(KubernetesClientApplication.scala:235)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.k8s.submit.KubernetesClientApplication$$anonfun$run$4.apply(KubernetesClientApplication.scala:235)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithResource(Utils.scala:2542)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.k8s.submit.KubernetesClientApplication.run(KubernetesClientApplication.scala:241)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.k8s.submit.KubernetesClientApplication.start(KubernetesClientApplication.scala:204)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:845)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:161)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:184)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:920)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:929)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

The java.io.FileNotFoundException error does not tell me in which file the problem, so I really do not understand where the problem is.

Also, no matter how I change the spark-submit code, I still get the same error.